# index page not rendering in nuxt js localhost 3000

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NrGhb.png)

I want my app to have multiple pages. I have already deleted the app.vue file and created the pages folder and index.vue  file in pages folder but still doesn't render in localhost3000

Comment: Do you run the dev server using `npm run dev` ? if yes then in which port it is serving check it. And lastly try to remove all code from index.vue run with a simple html in template check if it still not running

Comment: hi there,
first of all yes you should start the dev server with the `npm run dev` command and it by default runs on port 3000.
next in your index.vue that you attached you use GlobalAppHeader but it not defined or imported in your code

Comment: The default layout was messing with it

Answer (score 2):

The app.vue file is required to have routing.

`A minimal app.vue` [Source](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/guide/directory-structure/app)

```
<template>
  <div>
    <NuxtLayout>
      <NuxtPage/>
    </NuxtLayout>
  </div>
</template>
```

The `NuxtPage` will be the component that is used on your route. So on `localhost:3000` this would be `pages/index.vue`, on `localhost:3000/login` it would be `pages/login.vue`.

The `NuxtLayout` is optional and can be removed like below. But it doesn't do anything unless you have a `layouts` folder and have defined a default or on page layout. [More info](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/guide/directory-structure/layouts)

```
<template>
  <div>
    <NuxtPage/>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. The solution for me was to put NuxtLayout under self-closing tag, as below :

```
 <template>
   <NuxtLayout />
   <NuxtPage />
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it cannot automatically import the components. I think that the backslash in the path should be replaced with a slash:

Current: `components\global/AppHeader.vue`

Should be: `components/global/AppHeader.vue`

Answer (score 0):

As said in the [docs](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/components):

> For clarity, we recommend that the component's filename matches its
> name.

- So you're components should be located under `components/global/app`
  and should be named `GlobalAppHeader.vue` in your case.
- Also it seems that the auto-import doesn't behave correctly in Nuxt3 as described [here](https://github.com/nuxt/framework/issues/1044). It's better to declare components path explicitly for now.
  So in your `nuxt.config.ts` add the components entry, so it becomes:

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
 +   components: [
 +      '~/components/global/app/',
 +  ],
})
```

Remove the `.nuxt` folder in your project and run `yarn dev`.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Nope, you are wrong, his `GlobalAppHeader.vue` component is fine.

Comment: @Mises: Component is fine but the way it is loaded is not correct i think.